# Debian: unattended-upgrade does not reboot

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, upgrade

I have basically the same problem as described in this question : [unattended-upgrades does not reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/551594/unattended-upgrades-does-not-reboot)

On my Debian wheezy I installed unattended-upgrades which correctly upgrades my packages every night, but no reboot occurs when required (i've checked by running `checkrestart` which shows me many processes using old versions of upgraded files).

As mentioned here [unattended-upgrades does not reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/551594/unattended-upgrades-does-not-reboot) I installed `update-notifier-common`. But it still doesn't reboot when required.

Here is my config:

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these origin patterns
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "origin=Debian,archive=stable,label=Debian-Security";
};
Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";

// Send email to this address for problems or packages upgrades
// If empty or unset then no email is sent, make sure that you
// have a working mail setup on your system. A package that provides
// 'mailx' must be installed. E.g. "user@example.com"
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "[my email address]";

// Do automatic removal of new unused dependencies after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if a
// the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades

```
// Enable the update/upgrade script (0=disable)
APT::Periodic::Enable "1";

// Do "apt-get update" automatically every n-days (0=disable)
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";

// Run the "unattended-upgrade" security upgrade script
// every n-days (0=disabled)
// Requires the package "unattended-upgrades" and will write
// a log in /var/log/unattended-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Comment: Well, is there a file `/var/run/reboot-required`? When you log in, do you get a reboot required line? Not many updates set the reboot required flag (mostly kernel updated).

Comment: Nope, no such file, not reboot required line. Is it possible that some updates do not set the reboot flag, but still require services to be restarted?

Comment: It's the package mantainer's choice. Some packages (for example some libraries), when updated in interactive mode, ask for permission to restart services known to use them, but not to restart the computer. The computer absolutely needs to be restarted on kernel update.

Comment: Ok thx I understand now. So unattended-upgrade can update packages, restart the computer in case of kernel update, but won't restart services that need to be restarted. This makes unattended-upgrade much less useful then :(